# Phonegap does not display image on my Android Tablet

Tags: android, file, cordova

it's my first question and i dont know if i'm doing it right.

Well i've just startet to develop apps with phonegap, and in my application I need to take images from the camera and display it on the index page.

I did it and the app works perfectly on my phone but not in my tablet.

The code:

```
<img src='file:///mnt/sdcard/myapp/pic.jpg' />
```

This code shows the image previously saved on my phone but in my tablet browser does not find the image. The path is the same in both cases. Android version is the same (4.0.4). Phonegap version is 1.9.0.

Anyone knows why is happen that?

Thanks, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct on the tablet?

Comment: Yes is correct. I tried with "file:///mnt/sdcard/pic.jpg" and "/mnt/sdcard/pic.jpg" and doesn't work anyway!

Comment: Solved: I have to use the pat starting with /sdcard not from /mnt . The app works with the route /sdcard/myapp/pic.jpg